# Why dot notation can be used in method which return a block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learn block recently, I write a function which return a block,just like Masonry,

```
- (UIButton *(^)(NSString *title, UIControlState state))nj_buttonTitle {
    return ^UIButton *(NSString *title, UIControlState state) {
        [self setTitle:title forState:state];
        return self;
    };
}
```

then, I can call this method use dot notation without warning.

```
UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
b.nj_buttonTitle(@"hello", UIControlStateNormal);
```

and I also write a method like this

```
- (void)nj_print {
    NSLog(@"nj_print");
}
```

there is a warning `Property access result unused-getters should not be used for side effects` while I call this method use dot notation `b.nj_print`;

I guess because `nj_buttonTitle` return a block, and I use this block, so that there is no warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct - `nj_buttonTitle` method returns block, and your code immediately invokes it, so there is no warning in the first case.

In the second case, you are using dot syntax for a method with void return type. Dot syntax supposed to be used only for properties in Objective-C, so compiler warns you about incorrect usage.

Comment: you said Dot syntax supposed to be used only for properties in Objective-C, but I use it on method -`nj_buttonTitle`,is there some conflict?

Comment: Dot syntax is simply a syntax sugar. But implementing a methods that will return blocks only for the purpose that you can use dot syntax for calls will cause a lot of pain for other developers, that will look in your code. Please, don't do that.